# Stringing a search in two models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

The problem I have is to pass the chained search of two models to the template at the sight, these two databases are linked by a custom_id as shown below:

Note: This is an example of the interaction of the original model, which is very long

model:

```
from django.db import models

class Model (models.Model):
     custom_id = (max_length = 10)
     data = models.CharField (max_length = 100)

Model1 class (models.Model):
     models.IntegerField custom_id = (max_length = 10)

Model2 class (models.Model):
     relation2 = models.OneToOneField (Model1)

class UserProfile (models.Model):
     models.ForeignKey user = (User, unique = True)
     relation1 = models.ManyToManyField (Model2)
```

This shows me all this custom_id User log in on the page

```
custom = Model1.objects.filter (model2__userprofile__user__username = user)
```

The question is how to sack all the data related to this custom_id?

in terminal shows me the data and the two interactions with this for:

```
for element in custom:
     customid = str(elemento.custom_id)
     data = Model.objects.filter(customid=customid)
```

but I just keep one in the data.

Comment: custom [<custom_id: 45290>, <custom_id: 87345>]

Comment: alldata = Model.objects.filter(custom_id__in=custom) Not Working alldata [] in terminal!

Comment: As I look across all custom_id and filter with custom as QuerySets?

Comment: alldata = Model.objects.filter(custom_id=custom) DatabaseError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

Comment: I was reading achievement and nothing to solve. I was wondering if you can extend the queryset with multiple filters (for example would be the two custom_id) and filter all results by using custom and subsequently to make the data individually for each custom_id from the template? I also thought of making a variable for each custom queryset id and send it to the template, the problem is that you do to send as many plot a from the template, can be 10 custom_id as for example with a plot a:{% for element in custom %} {{id_{{elemento.custom_id}}}}
{% endfor %} is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it already.

Loads another variable to the template that contains this variable has to do a loop and contain my custom query:

```
from itertools import *

for element in custom:
    result = # operation
    query = chain (query, [result])
```

query functions in the same manner as in queryset template.